Is there a good way to circumvent the frequency limitation of mousemove events?
Mousemove events only fire at a limited frequency, which is determined by the implementation. I think in most browsers it depends on the speed of movement, and caps out at 70hz or so. This causes visible lag if you're trying to render something at the location of the mouse.
I attempted to circumvent this limitation by covering the screen with a grid of invisible divs with mouseenter event listeners. Unfortunately it looks like Chrome will start dropping mouseenter events if they're fired too frequently. Make the grid cells too large and the mouse isn't crossing boundaries frequently enough, make them too small and events start getting dropped. I found that a cell edge length of around 10px was best, which slightly increased dispatch frequency up to around 110hz, but this was not sufficient to eliminate the visible lag.
I suspect there are better ways to cheat browsers into giving me more fine-grained movement data, but it likely depends on implementation details that I don't know about. Any ideas?
